# MacBook Air 13 inch i5 processer

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, password

Hello I don’t know if there is a problem with my macbook just bought it yesterday and I found out that after I key in my password to enter the macbook there is always this progress bar and I ask my friends who own a macbook and none of them have the progress bar after entering the password.

Secondly I also notice that during the enter password page and the home page the battery shown on top is different after i enter the macbook for example: the battery show 96 percent then when Enter my password after the progress bar load finish and enter the home page it show me 100 percent.

Please help if you know anything thank you so much

Comment: Did you buy this new or used?  The fact that you see a progress bar *after* your password means it has FileVault enabled. If thats true, there may also be a firmware password.  If the previous owner didn’t clear these, it can be a huge problem - if you ever have to reset your Mac, you’ll be locked out with no way to recover.  Let me know what f this is new or used so I can answer appropriately.

Comment: I bought it from the Apple store it’s new

Comment: Did you have someone set it up for you?  Did you enable FileVault?  Check System Preferences -> Security & Privacy.  Also see: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837

Comment: No I set it up myself I think maybe i could have press something let me go check

Comment: The fire vault is turn on what should I do

Comment: The question is...did you set it up?  If you didn't then you got an open box (not new)  If you did, then things are OK.

Comment: I set it up myself and the open is not open is sealed I have turn off the FileVault

Comment: I didn't ask you to turn it off!  I'm trying to get a picture of what's going on.  If you set it up as new then it not a problem.  However, the way you asked the question left open the door that you were not aware of what was happening and you could have potentially gotten a used machine.  If you set up FileVault, you're fine, it uses your login credentials to unencrypt the drive and then you'll see a loading bar.  This is normal.

Comment: Ohh I’m so sorry I understand you thank you so much for helping me! This is my first time using macbook and no one help me setup so I did not know what is happening

Comment: No problem.  See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/396598/119271  it should answer your question - but what you're seeing is completely normal.